# Using XNA libraries in Windows Phone Silverlight Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I am developing for Windows Phone. I want to ask can I use XNA libraries in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. For example, when using MediaLibrary for playing songs, you have to use XNA libraries. If you want to mix XAML and XNA, you have a special project type just for that purpose. This is useful when building games that have lots of UI for leaderboards, settings, etc.